# 404 not found jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, http-status-code-404, response.redirect

This is post method of my login Servlet

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String login = request.getParameter("login").trim();
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    User user = getUsersDao().login(login, DigestUtils.shaHex(password));

    if (user == null) {
        request.setAttribute("login", login);
        request.setAttribute("error", "Wrong username or password.");
        forward(request, response, LOGIN_JSP);
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(USER_SESSION, user);
        response.sendRedirect(LOGGED_IN_URL);
    }
}
```

where `LOGGED_IN_URL is "WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp";`

and index.jsp exist on this addres, this doesn't work only after login. The if condition on user is ok (I checked it by setting it on false).

Why does it happens?

Answer (score 2):

Resources in `/WEB-INF` folder are not publicly accessible (otherwise the enduser would be able to see sensitive information such as datasource username/password in `web.xml` by just opening it directly).

You need to put the publicly accessibe JSP file outside the `/WEB-INF` folder.

```
LOGGED_IN_URL = "/index.jsp";
```

and redirect as follows

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + LOGGED_IN_URL);
```

Resources in `/WEB-INF` are only available for forward and include.

Comment: No more coffee at home this morning? :) Using `sendRedirect()` on a /WEB-INF located resources is not going to work, with or without /.

Comment: @Med: oops, I somehow interpreted that he was forwarding, answer is fixed.